# ncurses - can't print multiple times the same character with addstr and/or addch

Tags: c, ncurses

I have been playing around with ncurses in C a bit, and have been trying to get this little piece of code working correctly for an hour now.

I try to print a 3x3 field of the form: (just in 3x3 instead of 2x2)

```
00000
0 0 0
00000
0 0 0
00000
```

And I think my code is working correctly, no warnings or errors are appearing, but instead of `00000` it just displays `0`. 
I.e. when I change my code to display `abc` it does display it.

Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

void drawfield(uint16_t size, char c);
void quit();

int main(int argv, char **argc) {
    //read in the man page, that these settings should be good
    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    curs_set(0);
    atexit(quit);

    drawfield(20, 'b');
    refresh();

    getch();
    return 0;
}

void drawfield(uint16_t size, char c) {
    //Preparing strings
    char *line = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (size + 1));
    char *rest = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (size + 1));

    // line should be of format "ccccccccc", while rest should be "c   c   c"
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        // if i use c+i instead of c it seems to work fine
        *(line+i) = c;
        *(rest+i) = (i % (size/3))?' ':c;
    }
    line[size] = '\0';
    rest[size] = '\0';

    // debug output, strings seem to be correct
    printf("line: %s \n rest: %s \n", line, rest);
    sleep(3);

    //Drawing part
    //Should be drawing a 3x3 field
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        if (i % (size/3) == 0) {
            mvaddstr(i, 0, line);
        } else {
            mvaddstr(i, 0, rest);
        }
    }
}   
void quit() {
    endwin();
}
```

Output:
(the same character method):

```
b
b     b     b     b
b     b     b     b
b     b     b     b
b     b     b     b
b     b     b     b
b
b     b     b     b
b     b     b     b
b     b     b     b
b     b     b     b
b     b     b     b
b
b     b     b     b
b     b     b     b
b     b     b     b
b     b     b     b
b     b     b     b
b
b     b     b     b
```

(changing the character)

```
bcdefghijklmnopqrstu
b     b     b     b
b     b     b     b
b     b     b     b
b     b     b     b
b     b     b     b
bcdefghijklmnopqrstu
b     b     b     b
b     b     b     b
b     b     b     b
b     b     b     b
b     b     b     b
bcdefghijklmnopqrstu
b     b     b     b
b     b     b     b
b     b     b     b
b     b     b     b
b     b     b     b
bcdefghijklmnopqrstu
b     b     b     b
```

I also directly tried using the addch method instead of addstr, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

If you know why this happens and/or how to work around it, I would really like to know!
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: 
I'm using ArcoLinux as my distro and gcc as the compiler using the `-lncurses` flag

EDIT 2: 
The problem was that I was using urxvt, but had set the TERM variable to `xterm-256color` instead of `rxvt-256color`. Changing this via my .Xresources files `termName` entry fixed it.

Comment: OT I can't help but wonder who keeps telling people to use `*(x+i)` instead of `x[i]`?

Comment: At first I accessed the strings the array way, but changed it later on hoping it would change anything.

Comment: Cannot reproduce your problem, am seeing `bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb`

Comment: @ThomasDickey Thank you very much, changing the `TERM` variable via my `.Xresources` file seems to fix it.

Comment: Props for getting the `sizeof(char) * (size + 1)` formula logically correct, but `sizeof (char)` is 1 by definition, so you can just do `size + 1`.